# Twodimensional array into a UILabel

Tags: objective-c

I have a twodimensional array where i i would like to print all second values of the objects into an UIlabel homePlayersFouls. the problem is i do not know how to this.

I have tried following things:

```
componentsJoinedByString:@"\n".
```

This will just print (

The other thing ive tried is this:

```
[[homePlayersArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1];
```

this just prints 0 since it looping and deleting the content inside label

i've checked wether there is something wrong the the array, but when i do this inside the loop:

```
nslog(@"%@",[[homePlayersArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1];);
```

It prints all 0 0 0 which is the 3 second values in my objects.

The question is then how can i print all my second values in all the objects in  the array into an UIlabel?

here is the complete code:

```
for (int i=0;i<[homeNumbersArray count];i++){
    NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[homeNumbersArray objectAtIndex:i],[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
    [homePlayersArray addObject:tempArray];
    NSObject* someObject = [[homePlayersArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1];
    homePlayersFouls.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someObject];

}
```

Comment: Of course `[[homePlayersArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1]` is the *second* element in each subarray. The first element has index zero.

Comment: example if in the array it is {3, 0}, {2, 0}, {4, 0}
it is suppose to print 0 0 0 in the label, but it only prints 0. how can i obtain this?

Comment: You *overwrite* `homePlayersFouls.text` in each loop iteration. You probably want to *append* text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
homePlayersFouls.text = [homePlayersFouls.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someObject]];
```

Comment: How about `[homePlayersFouls.text stringByAppendingString:[someObject description]]` instead?

Comment: @BlackRider ya that would probably be better. Should really be using a property instead of relying on the description in any case.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *fouls = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i=0;i<[homeNumbersArray count];i++){
    NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[homeNumbersArray objectAtIndex:i],[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
    [homePlayersArray addObject:tempArray];
    NSObject* someObject = [[homePlayersArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1];
    [fouls appendFormat:@"%@", someObject];

}

homePlayersFouls.text = fouls;
```